# ascii table counter with Java not returning null as false

Tags: java, ascii, counter

I try to validate if the user has input a number 0-9 or if it has a decimal. It does validate if it is a number or a letter but if the user doesn't put anything the loop still runs as if it is a valid number.

So, there are two bugs:

1. User hits enter before inputting a valid floating point number and the script still runs as valid.
2. User enters a period without entering any numbers and the script still runs as valid.

```
package numbers;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class IsAValidNumber
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //console input scanner
        Scanner consoleInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        //Prompt user for input
        System.out.print("enter a valid number:");
        String validat = consoleInput.nextLine();

        boolean isTrue = NumberIsValid(validat);
        while(isTrue == true)
        {
            System.out.println(validat + " is a valid number. Please enter another value:");
            validat = consoleInput.nextLine();
            isTrue = NumberIsValid(validat);
        }
        //if it jumps out of the while because it is false run this
        System.out.println(validat + " is not a valid number, bye");
        consoleInput.close();
    }
    
    public static boolean NumberIsValid(String value)
    {
        int period = 0;
        boolean valid = true;
        int length = value.length();
        
        //run through the string
        //check the numbers
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            char aChar = value.charAt(i);
            // make sure it doesn't start with a space
            if((int)aChar == 20)
            {
                valid =false;
                break;
            }
            
            // check to make sure its is a int 0-9
            else if((int)aChar < 48 || (int)aChar > 57)
            {
                if((int)aChar == 46)
                {
                    period++;
                }
                else
                {
                    valid = false;
                    break;
                }
                
            }

            //make sure it doesn't have more than one period
            if (period > 1)
            {   
                valid = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        return valid;
    }
}
```

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For bug #1: in your method `NumberIsValid(String value)`, you never check if the argument is empty or not. When an empty argument is passed to your method, the for loop is skipped and it returns true.

For bug #2: Not the best solution, but you could simply create something like this:

```
    if (value.contains(".") && length == 1) {
        return false
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Bug #2 fix is working great. I'm still having a little trouble with #1. When should I check in the input isEmpty()? These loops have me looping my brain around itself!

Comment: It doesn't really matter. I would just check to see if the input is empty after the line `int length = value.length()`.

Answer (score 0):

After some much need help, the solution is listed below. The fix to bug #1 was to implement a way to check the passing string to see if it was empty. And the fix to bug #2 was to check if the user only input a period and there was only one character length. Pretty smart on @Flaom's part.

Fix #1: make sure to input before it starts the for loop

```
//validate to see if string is empty before starting!
        if(value.isEmpty() )
        {
            valid = false;

        }
```

Fix #2:

```
// check to see if user only input a period
        if (value.contains(".") && length == 1) {
            valid = false;
        }
```

Please view the coding below to see exactly where to place.

```
package numbers;

    /*
     * File name: IsAValidNumber.java
     * Project name: Is a Valid Number
     * 
     * Creator's name: Joshua Trimm
     * Email: jbthype@gmail.com
     * Course and section: CISP 1010
     * Creation Date: 10-9-17
     */

    import java.util.Scanner;
    /*
     * <b>Floating point value validation</b>
     * <hr>
     * Date created: 10-9-2017
     * <hr>
     * @author Joshua Trimm
     * 
     */
    public class IsAValidNumber
    {


        /*
         * Method description: This is the main method
         * @param args
         * @return void
         */

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

            //console input scanner
            Scanner consoleInput = new Scanner(System.in);


            //Prompt user for input
            System.out.print("enter a valid number:");
            String validat = consoleInput.nextLine();
            //define boolean from method
            boolean isTrue = NumberIsValid(validat);
            //while loop
            while(isTrue == true)
            {


                System.out.println(validat + " is a valid number. Please enter another value:");
                validat = consoleInput.nextLine();
                isTrue = NumberIsValid(validat);


            }
            //if it jumps out of the while because it is false run this
            System.out.println(validat + " is not a valid number, bye");
            consoleInput.close();
        }
        /*
         * Method description: Setup a boolean method
         * @param string
         * @return boolean
         */
        public static boolean NumberIsValid(String value)
        {

            //define local variables
            int period = 0;
            boolean valid = true;
            int length = value.length();
            int digitCount = 0;


            //validate to see if string is empty before starting!
            if(value.isEmpty() )
            {
                valid = false;

            }

            //Start running through the string
            for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {


                char aChar = value.charAt(i);


                // check to make sure its is a int 0-9
                if((int)aChar < 48 || (int)aChar > 57)
                {
                // check for the period 
                    if((int)aChar == 46)
                    {
                        period++;
                        if(length < 2)
                        {
                            valid = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        valid = false;
                        break;
                    }

                }

                //make sure it doesn't have more than one period

                if (period > 1)
                {   
                    valid = false;
                    break;
                }

                // check to see if user only input a period
                if (value.contains(".") && length == 1) {
                    valid = false;
                }
            }


            return valid;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all in your code you are checking the non favorable cases but i will suggest you to check only for favorable cases as to check for number 1 to 9 and single occurrence of the "." I changed your method a little bit

```
  public static boolean NumberIsValid(String value)
{


    int period = 0;
    boolean valid = false;


    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
    if(value.charAt(i)>=48 && value.charAt(i)<=57) valid=true;
    if(value.charAt(i)==46) {valid=true;period++;}
    if(period!=1 && period!=0) {valid=false;break;}

    }


    return valid;

}
```

By this code we are checking only for 0 to 9 and the single occurrence of "." if any other condition will occur it will return false.
In this way we can make it simple
you add this method in your code and just compile and let me know if you are facing the same issue again.